# how to move to new laptop/desktop (windows)

Tags: windows, replication, migration

I have a windows desktop for development purpose.

The desktop runs windows xp, is only used by single user. It has many applications like Java, ClearCase client, Filezilla, firefox, Outlook  and lot others.

A new machine is on the way(with Windows 7). Current strategy is to create a backup folder. Move every valuable data there. Copy the data onto new machine.  Is there a betterway ? do I move to new machine with minimum disruption?

If I boot both machines with Linux and do an rsync appropriate folders will it save anytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of these 2 guides made by How-To Geek could help you out: you can do it either with an [Easy Transfer cable](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3179/migrate-xp-to-windows-7-with-easy-transfer-and-a-usb-drive/) or via the [network](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3157/migrate-xp-to-windows-7-with-easy-transfer-over-the-network/).

Comment: Not tried yet. Should work :)